# Ajax call issue on click event in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I need to know about using ajax in nodejs.
Im using this code in my nodejs application

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {


    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "/test1", true);
  xhttp.send();
```

The issue is that it is called only 6 times on click event.
It is slow on 7th and 8th time and so on.
It works well on page refresh but does not work on click event.

My server side code :-

```
router.post('/test1', function(req, res){
                console.log("TEST1");

});
```

Comment: Your server never tells the client the request is finished. So on the 7/8th request you probably still have 7 requests still open waiting on a response from your sever (that will eventually time out)

Answer (score 1):

Try returning back something to the client as response:

```
res.send('');
```

Alternatively you can use `next()` to send control back to the client:

```
router.post('/test1', function(req, res, next){
    console.log("TEST1"); next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sai Ram Kota, it worked. And I still wonder it was working on page refresh without any server response.